# What is the most used expression to express the gratitude for someone's attentions

Tags: american-english, expressions, writing, spoken-english

I was wondering which one among the following expressions is the most used in written and spoken American English to express gratitude for someone's attention—for example, when someone asks if you are OK after an accident.

> Thank you for your caring/care/concern/concerns/attentions ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'attention' or 'attentions'. That is not a word that native speakers use in this context. A thing we might say is *Thank you for your concern* but even then a simple *Thank you* is often enough.

Comment: @User1 by "attention" I mean when someone asks if you are OK after an accident for ex.

Comment: Then I would probably say, *Yes, I am, thank you.* And maybe: *It's nice of you to ask.*

Comment: I have edited your question to include the matter in your comment and your tags. It is very helpful for answerers to have this sort of thing *in the body of the question*, so they don't have to search through the other stuff; and it will help you get an answer quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your choices, I would choose

> Thank you for your concern.

However, in real life, I would say something like the following:

> Yes, I am, thank you.

Perhaps followed by *It was nice of you to ask.*